# No traffic captured in wireshark in monitor mode npcap

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, wireshark, sniffing

I am using npcap drivers (latest 0.9995) on windows 7. I can set the mode of my wireless card to `monitor` mode using `wlanhelper "Wifi interface" mode monitor`. It changes to `mon` mode successfully and wifi connection is lost.

When I start wireshark (both as admin and as normal user) I cannot see any packet on the interface. I tried toggling capture options (`promiscuous mode, monitor`) and nothing happens as long as the card is in `mon` mode.

I can capture ethernet traffic when the card is in `managed` mode as usual. Any help will be appreciated.

My wireless card is: `Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter`. I think it supports `mon` mode well.

Comment: What channel did you tune the card to? What channel is your target AP on? The fact that you didn't mention channels suggests to me that you weren't mindful of them, and may have been sniffing on a channel with no traffic.

Comment: The `Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter` is listed as a supported adapter, at least for Windows 7 v6.1.7601 at https://secwiki.org/w/Npcap/WiFi_adapters, so in theory this adapter should work.  It's possible updates to Npcap broke compatibility though, as the version of Npcap tested was 0.99-r9 and you're now using the latest 0.9995.  You could try retesting with the older Npcap release to see if it helps?  You should be able to get it from here: https://nmap.org/npcap/dist/

Comment: @Spiff I cannot set channel because ```wlanhelper "Wi-Fi" channel x``` gives ```Error: makeOIDRequest::My_PacketOpenAdapter error (to use this function, you need to check the "Support raw 802.11 traffic" option when installing Npcap)```. But I tried changing channels in my AP.

Comment: The previous error comes even in freq or mode (without manage or monitor) command.

Comment: @ChristopherMaynard I tried with 0.99-r9. It gave two mishaps: 1. *NO* monitor option in wireshark. 2. Even after uninstalling wifi has got a limited access, which I had to use system restore to fix!!

Comment: @ratcher86 Sounds like you installed npcap wrong then. Raw 802.11 frames is what monitor mode is all about.

Comment: Sorry for the above comment. I installed npcap right (with raw 802.11), but actualy installed 0.09-r9 instead of 0.99-r9. :/. 0.99-r9 works, I can capture signals, but frequent bsods are pain ::cry:: .Even starting wifi ap is giving bsod...

Comment: Seems like something broke between 0.99-r9 and 0.9994. I'll try to trace if got time. Thank you @ChristopherMaynard